# livewire does not update value

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

i starting to use livewire and I know practically nothing.

the problem is that it doesn't update my counter without reloading the page:

[Counter Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq4pP.png)

when I enter a new request remains the same value without updating

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Rrppsolicitudes;
use App\Models\Dias;
use Auth;

class Counter extends Component
{




    public function render(Request $request)
    {

       $evento = request()->segments()[1];
        $rrpp = Auth::user()->id;
        $counter = Rrppsolicitudes::where('evento_id' , $evento)->where('rrpp_id', $rrpp)->whereNull('estado')->count('id');
    
        return view('livewire.counter',compact('counter'));
    }
}
```

blade:

```
    <div style="background-color: #ff4040;
width: 117px;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
border-radius: 15px;" class="text-center mx-auto">{{$counter}} Solicitudes</div>
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Are you expecting that livewire would update the count of `Rrppsolicitudes` when a new row is added to your database? 
You're creating the `Rrppsolicitudes` on a livewire component as well?

Answer (score 1):

If `$counter` is being updated by something outside of your component, the component won't know to refresh.

You can add [`wire:poll`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/polling) to your component or a part of it, which will refresh its values regularly.

Alternatively, you could have whatever's updating your `$counter` broadcast that change, and [have Livewire listen for the broadcast using Laravel Echo](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/laravel-echo). More complicated, but easier on the server and more immediate updates.

Comment: wire:poll  works, but returns the counter to 0

Comment: @JeremiasRosas That's probably because you're doing `$evento = request()->segments()[1];` when you should really be using route parameters. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#route-params

Comment: okay, @ceejayoz should I have two routes with the same URL?

Comment: @JeremiasRosas Your route would be something like `Route::get('/evento/{evento}', YourComponent::class);`, which you can then access in your controller as explained in the documentation I linked. You should never manually be playing with `request()->segments()` stuff; in Livewire's case, it won't be what you expect on an update, because those go through a Livewire URL like `livewire/messages`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at [Livewire - Computed Properties](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#computed-properties)

```php
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Rrppsolicitudes;
use App\Models\Dias;
use Auth;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public function getCounterProperty()
    {
        return Rrppsolicitudes::where('evento_id' , $evento)
            ->where('rrpp_id', $rrpp)
            ->whereNull('estado')
            ->count('id');
    }

    public function render(Request $request)
    {

       $evento = request()->segments()[1];
        $rrpp = Auth::user()->id;
    
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}
```

Comment: What variable do I receive in the view 'livewire.counter'?

Comment: Computed Property defined as `getCounterProperty` will be available as `$counter` in the view. I have given a link to the documentation you can refer for more on that. Convention is very similar to Laravel, where we define computed property/accessor as `get[Name]Attribute` while in Livewire it is `get[Name]Property`

Comment: the variable in getCounterProperty  would be:   $counter = $this->counter;  ??

Comment: Yes it will be available as `$this->counter` and not `$counter` sorry my bad. And as @ceejayoz has mentioned have a look at the link he provided for using route params with Livewire